# How can I expand/collapse ddaccordion from asp.net code behind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using [ddaccordion](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ddaccordion.htm) for replacing Ajax CollapsiblePanelExtender. I want to achieve same behaviour as Ajax CPE using ddaccordion.

I have two requirements:

1) I need to check some conditions on code behind based on that expand/collapse the panel. How can I do it?

2) I have set persiststate: true, //persist state of opened contents within browser session?
Its clearly mentioned here the state persists untill the broswer get closed but I need to keep the state within the postbacks only.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.

Just sharing solution to the second problem.

On master aspx page I have put this javascript code.

```
var isPostBack = "<%#Page.IsPostBack.ToString().ToLower()%>";
            if (isPostBack == "false") {
                deleteCookie(cookiename);
            }

function setCookie(name, value, days) { if (days) { var date = new Date(); date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString(); } else var expires = ""; document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/"; }
function deleteCookie(name) { setCookie(name, "", -1); }
```